# Django Postgres ArrayField aggregation and filtering

Tags: django, postgresql, django-contrib

Following on from this question: [Django Postgresql ArrayField aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748136/django-postgresql-arrayfield-aggregation)

I have an `ArrayField` of Categories and I would like to retrieve all unique values it has - however the results should be filtered so that only values starting with the supplied string are returned.

What's the "most Django" way of doing this?

Given an `Animal` model that looks like this:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    # ...
    categories = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True),
        default=list,
    )
    # ...
```

Then, as per [the other question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32749042/1286705), this works for finding all categories, unfiltered.

```
all_categories = (
    Animal.objects
    .annotate(categories_element=Func(F('categories'), function='unnest'))
    .values_list('categories_element', flat=True)
    .distinct()
)
```

However, now, when I attempt to filter the result I get failure, not just with `__startswith` but all types of `filter`:

```
all_categories.filter(categories_element__startswith('ga'))
all_categories.filter(categories_element='dog')
```

Bottom of stacktrace is:

```
DataError: malformed array literal: "dog"
...
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

... and it appears that it's because Django tries to do a second `UNNEST` - this is the SQL it generates:

```
...) WHERE unnest("animal"."categories") = dog::text[]
```

If I write the query in PSQL then it appears to require a subquery as a result of the `UNNEST`:

```
SELECT categories_element
FROM (
    SELECT UNNEST(animal.categories) as categories_element
) ul
WHERE ul.categories_element like 'Ga%';
```

Is there a way to get Django ORM to make a working query? Or should I just give up on the ORM and use raw SQL?

Comment: can maybe use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#extra to get the subquery in there. `annotate` seems kind of wrong (it's usually for aggregation type functions)

Comment: Thanks @Anentropic - I did have a look at `extra` but couldn't see a way to add the subquery. The answer below is probably the "truest" - the schema is not fit for purpose really. I've implemented a mini query builder that selects and sorts from the ArrayFields and appears to be working nicely.

Comment: I wondered if you could put the subquery in `tables` parameter

Answer (score 2):

You probably have the wrong database design.

> Tip: Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be
>   a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a
>   row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier
>   to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of
>   elements.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html

Comment: Yes I completely agree that the design is not optimal. But it's not my design and I'm stuck with it for now :( Poor `Animal`s!

Comment: In that case there is no reason why shouldn't use a raw query. Raw queries are not evil.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a go!