# How to fetch arrayfield data in django with postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to fetch users list based on their language(from ArrayField). A single user can have multiple languages. When i passed single language`{'Hindi'}`, it fetches all the records except user with multiple languages, but if passed parameters `{'Hindi','bangla','kannada'}` then it gives me a specific record,how can i fetch the users list with `hindi` and other than `hindi` as well . I have tried with `.all` also but it didn't worked for me. 
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]
models.py

```
# DESCRIPTION: This function gets the drivers list by lang.
    @classmethod
    def get_driver_by_lang(cls, driver_lang):
        try:
            driver_details = cls.objects.filter(language = driver_lang)
            data = serializers.serialize("json", driver_details)
            data = json.loads(data)
            return data
        except :
            return False
```

Comment: try the suggested answer and the comment.

Comment: also you probably have the wrong database design. searching for specific array elements can be a sign of database misdesign. check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36742834/3868653)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
driver_details = cls.objects.filter(language__contains = driver_lang)
```

Comment: won't it be `cls.objects.filter(language__contains=[driver_lang])`?

Comment: without '[]' it is working. let me check again with [].

Comment: with the [] it gives an error, but without it , its working. Thanks @mhd