# Django - Query latest date in an ArrayField

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I'm making use of Django's postgres `ArrayField`.

Say I have a model like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dates = ArrayField(models.DateField())
```

And I want to find the `Event` with the latest date.  Is there a way to build a queryset that can do that?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have a surrogate table with `EventDates`?

Comment: Possibly, but currently the DB is the way it is and has a ton of data in it.  I'm hoping to find out if it can be done with an ArrayField before making a major schema change and data migration.  Also, this particular table is pummeled pretty hard and needs to be fast for most date-related queries (other than this particular max-date query - which doesn't _need_ to be uber fast as it won't be needed as often), so I'd like to avoid joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot get into the details of Django (I am not so much proficient in it). However, some pointers:

1. Using directly the SQL language, you would use:

   ```
   SELECT
       name, (SELECT max(d) FROM unnest(dates) d) AS latest_date
   FROM
       Event ;
   ```
2. To *backconvert* this to Django, check [Django Postgresql ArrayField aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748136/django-postgresql-arrayfield-aggregation), and adapt it to your specifc case.

   I think something along the lines of the following code should do the trick<sup>1</sup>:

   ```
   Event.objects.annotate(arr_els=Func(F('dates'), function='unnest')) \
           .values_list('arr_els', flat=True).aggregate(Max('arr_els'))
   ```

---

See the SQL example at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=3b4dbae912375fdb2cf232c7fc9ea373)*.

<sup>1)</sup> I do not have the right environment to test the Django part... so, this is untested.

Comment: Did you actually try the code? Did you have to modify it?

Comment: Yes, I did.  The above actually finds the latest date among the `Event`s, rather than the `Event` with the latest date.  But that's actually what I was ultimately trying to get, anyway.  And if I want the `Event`, that's easy enough to query once I have the date.