# Django ORM value_lists() unpack ArrayListField

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

So I have a model something like this

```
class Record(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    synonyms = ArrayField(models.CharField())
```

and I do have the following records:

```
Record 1 = Record(name=rec1, synonyms=['a','b'])
Record 2 = Record(name=rec2, synonyms=['c'])
Record 3 = Record(name=rec3, synonyms=['d','e'])
```

I want to get only synonyms for all records in a list.

I've tried:

```
synonyms_list = Record.objects.all().values_list('synonyms')
```

And it return:

```
[['a','b'],['c'],['d','e']]
```

But i want it to unpack the synonym list and I want the result to be something like this

```
['a','b','c','d','e']
```

Is it possible to do it using Django ORM or using postgres query ?

Comment: Why not `[x for xs in Record.objects.values_list('synonyms', flat=True) for x in xs]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748136/django-postgresql-arrayfield-aggregation) you can do for your model:

```
Record.objects.annotate(
    synonyms_flat=Func(F('synonyms'), function='unnest')
).values_list('synonyms_flat', flat=True)
```

Comment: Just like what I've been looking for ! Thanks !